# Length function is throwing an uncaught error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is an error when this code gets executed.
The code is working fine but its throwing an uncaught error.
Should I be concerned about this ?

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);     
}   

document.getElementById(type).options.length = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < response.length ; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
  option.innerHTML = response[i];
  option.value = response[i];
  ddlEnvType.options.add(option);
}

document.getElementById(type).disabled = false;

};
xmlhttp.open("POST","sample.php?condition=" +x.value +"&type=" +type,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do by `document.getElementById(type).options.length = 0;`

Comment: The last `}` needs to go as well.

Comment: I was trying to define it by manually setting it to 0 before the ajax is loaded and the length of options is changed.

Comment: Don't try and set the length property. Just leave it alone. Also you should always be concerned about uncaught errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(type).options.length = 0;
```

The above line is throwing error because `.length` is used to return the `length` and cannot be used to assign values to it.

In the for loop

```
i<response.length
```

but response is not an array its a JSON object which is the cause of the error

```
response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Comment: I tried removing it,but the error is coming in the for loop.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (ajaxCall.js:35)

Comment: This is the error that i'm getting and its been pointing to the length at for loop.

Comment: hey,Thank you so much,I converted the variable into array.Now its working.